# How to create elements (links) with 2 or more colors with CSS to make it look like a rainbow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, styles

When styling links between nodes in D3.js it is possible to change the color of the links. In the code below i use very thick links with a width of 10 and the stoke color grey.

```
link = svg.append("g")
.
.
.
.style("stroke", "grey")
.style("stroke-width", "10px")
```

Do you guys know how to style the links in a way to get 2 colors or more for 1 link? Make the link look like a rainbow? Meaning that a link has 2 colors or more from the begin of the link to the end of the link. I tried with D3.js only but that did not work. Is there someone who knows a CSS solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would think that you'd want to use CSS linear gradients as a background color for the element.

Comment: You can use gradients for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you want multiple color text use:

```css
.rainbow {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );
  background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );
  color:transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<div class='rainbow'> This is test text</div>
```

Comment: Wow, this is great!. Do you know, if this works for EVERY element? that means also for strokes?

Answer (score 2):

**[CSS Linear Gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)** would be the best bet.

```css
#grad1 {
    height: 200px;
    background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, orange , yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, orange , yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="grad1">Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go [Tehere](http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator) And generate gradient color, Then copy paste the code in your CSS